# click event auto triggered on knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying on [mail client tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) on learn.knockoutjs.com. I want to add a "back button" in mail detail block. But that button is auto triggered.

my codes

```
<div class="viewMail" data-bind="with: chosenMailData">
    <button data-bind="click: alert('derp')">derp</button>
    <div class="mailInfo">
        <h1 data-bind="text: subject"></h1>
        <p><label>From</label>: <span data-bind="text: from"></span></p>
        <p><label>To</label>: <span data-bind="text: to"></span></p>
        <p><label>Date</label>: <span data-bind="text: date"></span></p>
    </div>
    <p class="message" data-bind="html: messageContent" />
</div>
```

when i set **chosenMailData** viewMail div is show. But same time browser alert "derp". I want to when i click button, browser alert at that time. what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [KnockOutJs: Why does click data-bind has execute on-load of element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276164/knockoutjs-why-does-click-data-bind-has-execute-on-load-of-element)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The alert code will be executed when the with binding renders the content.

Either wrap it in a function or move it to a function in the view model

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { alert('derp'); }">derp</button>
```

Comment: I had to use the markup <button data-bind="click: function() { ..... }">derp</button>, and make a call to a function on the view model to make it work

Comment: You shouldn't put code in the view, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just followed the instructions in your answer "move it to a function in the view model"

Comment: Then you shouldnt need to wrap it in a function in the view, just do click: functonNameOnModel

Comment: You are right, I tried to pass the element data as a parameter in the function call, but I noticed the element is passed as a parameter anyway without explicitly passing it in a parameter.