# KnockOutJs: Why does click data-bind has execute on-load of element?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a anchor link generated via php which will be binded on ko and works fine. My problem is why does the ko function is executed on load of the elements? below is the code generated.

html:

```
<a data-bind="click: addOrderedProducts(11,"CRM130930001","Cream",0.00,0,0,0)" class="Add" title="Add" href="">Add</a>
```

ko function:

```
self.addOrderedProducts = function (id,product_number,name,price,quantity,discount,balance){
    self.orderedProducts.push(new Product(id,product_number,name,price,quantity,discount,balance));
};
```

please help me... Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is how object literals are working in Javascript so the property values like function class immediately evaluated when the object gets created.

To make it work you need to wrap your function call in the `click` binding into an anonymous function:

```
<a data-bind="click: function () { addOrderedProducts( ... ) }" href="">Add</a>
```

See also in the documentation: [Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_2_accessing_the_event_object_or_passing_more_parameters)

Comment: @nemesv What does inlining a function like this do with memory - do you have potential for a memory leak or delayed garbage collection?

Comment: @DavidRobbins The point is that the `click` takes a function reference so it does not matter whether it's defined inline or on your view-model. If you don't do anything bad in your handler function (which would prevent it from being GCed) it gets garbage collected when the element is removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, you could use `...click: addOrderedProducts.bind($data,...)` which I think is slightly cleaner (though it's somewhat a matter of personal taste).

`bind` is an ES5 method (Knockout shims it for non-ES5 browsers) of `function` objects which returns a new anonymous function that, when invoked, will take its context (i.e. its `this` value) from the first argument to `bind` and its first few arguments from any additional arguments passed to `bind`).

BTW (although nobody did it here) it's worth mentioning that it's never necessary to write something like:

```
functionWithCallback(..., function(data) {
  someOtherFunction(data);
});
```

Instead you can just write

```
functionWithCallback(..., someOtherFunction);
```

A function's name *is* as much of a function reference as an anonymous function expression; it's not necessary to write the latter in order to get one (of course you do need an anonymous function if the callback involves more code than just a single function call).

Answer (score 0):

from official [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) :

```
<button data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 'param1', 'param2')">Click me</button>
```