# How to use Knockout.js to change a CSS class on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css, html, knockout.js

I have a grid of images populated by a Knockout.js `foreach` data binding. By default, each image in the grid has a black outline set by the background colour. When the user mouses over each image, I would like that outline to turn white to signify that it has been highlighted.

Currently, I am using two event handlers, one for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseleave`.
 The first changes the image's CSS class to one with a white background. The latter changes it back to black. However, both get called (confirmed by debugging) when the mouse enters an image, so no change is seen.

The HTML is as follows:
(Notes: Each image has a `fileName` attribute representing the location of the image file. There are two `CSS` classes called `black` and `white`, one for each of the highlight states.)

```
<div id="palette-container" data-bind="foreach: images" style="display: inline-block">
    <div style="float: left">
        <img class="black" data-bind="attr: { id: fileName, src: $parent.imagePath(fileName) }, 
                                      event: { mouseenter: $parent.toWhite(fileName), mouseleave: $parent.toBlack(fileName) }, 
                                      style: { width: $parent.size, height: $parent.size }">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm not doing this in a very elegant way right now. I'm binding each element's `id` to its unique fileName attribute. Then I'm passing the fileName into the event handler so that the element can be accessed by id to change the CSS class.

(A) Why are both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` being called when the mouse enters an image?

(B) What's a simpler way of implementing the desired highlighting functionality?

Comment: Answer to A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276164/knockoutjs-why-does-click-data-bind-has-execute-on-load-of-element/19276222#19276222

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why all the event handlers were getting called on load. That's useful to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not to keep it simple. Use css `:hover`

```
//add a hover effect to class .black
.black{ 
border: solid 5px black
} .black:hover { 
border: solid 5px green;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmx2og9g/1/

Comment: Worked to perfection, thank you! I still wish I understood why both the event handlers were being called. But no matter. Simplicity wins here.

Comment: @JamesEdwardBrill You could simplify it even more by only redefining the property you want to change. `.black:hover { border-color: green; }`.

Answer (score 9):

Knockout's purpose is to connect (bind) the view (your HTML) to your viewmodel (a JavaScript object) declaratively, by means of *binding handlers*. However, not every possible DOM-to-viewmodel interaction has a predefined binding handler.

In your specific case (change a style) you could simply use the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class. Your view would respond to a mouse movement, but your viewmodel would not notice any of that.

If you want to change a different DOM property in response to a mouse move, for example the text of an element, CSS won't work anymore. You can either use knockout's `event` binding "manually" - or you can create a custom binding handler that sets one of the viewmodel's properties in response to the *mouseenter* and *mouseleave* events.

The advantages of a custom binding handler are that you now have an actual observable that you can base other behavior on, and that you have less typing to do in the view, which is good when you use it more than once.

The following changes both the element's text and CSS class on hover:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.hover = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            event: {
                mouseenter: function () { value(true) },
                mouseleave: function () { value(false) }
            }
        });
    }
}

function Item() {
  this.isHovering = ko.observable(false);
}

ko.applyBindings({
  items: [
    new Item(),
    new Item(),
    new Item(),
    new Item(),
    new Item()
  ]
});
```

```css
div.item {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
div.item.active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div class="item" data-bind="
    hover: isHovering, text: isHovering, css: {active: isHovering}
  ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent answer if the :hover css is data-bound.